# IE cannot access HTTPS sites (FF can), Win Update error 800728f8

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, https, internet-explorer-11

Been working on a machine for a while. Through IE11 on Win 7 I cannot access any HTTPS sites. Also, Win Update gives error 800728f8, which is usually clock-related. The clock is correct.

I've reset and re-registered w32time, Ran a full set of malware/av scans. Ran SFC /scannow, which found no errors. Checked that the GTE Worldwide cert is there. Disabled firewall altogether and tested. No Proxy server set up.

Still can't get this machine to work and update. Any ideas?

Comment: Which IE version? Older IE versions may have issues with 'newer' SSL crypto. You can use https://ssllabs.com to check the websites you're having problems with and see if your IE version is supported by that site or not.

Comment: IE11. Added this to original post.

Comment: In that case my remarks on older crypto are irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, should have noted OS and IE versions. Very strange. That FF/Chrome can visit these sites and that IE can visit all non-https sites, is interesting.

Comment: posted here as well: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/cannot-access-https-sites-windows-update/17f742cc-2716-4156-ac53-2ef9a7bdf968?tm=1453740398886